# Spring JMS and Oracle AQ

Tags: java, oracle, spring

Has anyone got Spring JMS to work with an Oracle AQ queue?

I am trying to connect to AQ based on this article
http://blog.nominet.org.uk/tech/2007/10/04/spring-jms-with-oracle-aq/

but i am getting this error now
JMS-137: Payload factory must be specified for destinations with ADT payloads

Any help with this is much appreciated

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error indicates to me it's actually working but you're not giving it a payload factory to create the object coming off the queue.  You do that when you create the receiver.  In this case my payload is XMLTYPE so I just use its payload factory:

```
queueReceiver = ((AQjmsSession) queueSession).
   createReceiver(queue, XMLType.getORADataFactory());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to supply a JDBC type map when you want to en-queue or de-queue AnyDataType or User Defined Payloads.

The best place to do it, in the Link you have posted will be in OracleAqDestinationFactoryBean.getObject.

In my case, I wanted to de-queue Oracle LCRs which are of XMLType , so I had to do the following in the getObject

```
public Object getObject() throws Exception {
    QueueConnection queueConnection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
    AQjmsSession session = (AQjmsSession) queueConnection.createQueueSession(true,
            Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
    Map map = session.getTypeMap();
    map.put("SYS.XMLTYPE", Class.forName("oracle.xdb.XMLTypeFactory"));
    return session.getQueue(queueUser, queueName);
}
```

Remember for AnyDataType Payload you have to use OCI JDBC driver, as the thin driver won't do.

More info on custom payload here
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14257/aq_stage.htm#sthref2705

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can solve it if you are using Spring: http://blog.javaforge.net/post/30858904340/oracle-advanced-queuing-spring-custom-types

In a "springless" environment just create your own message consumer like described in the blog post above.