# Connecting to Oracle Advance Queueing With Oracle Object Type Messages

Tags: oracle, mule

The Mule documentation gives an [example](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3EXAMPLES/Connecting+to+Oracle+AQ) on how to connect to Oracle AQ using a queue table with the `queue_payload_type` set to `sys.aq$_jms_text_message`.

How would I get Mule to work with `queue_payload_type` set to my own Oracle Object Type?

When I try to run the flow, I get the following error: `JMS-137: Payload factory must be specified for destinations with ADT payloads`. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450925/spring-jms-and-oracle-aq) and [this Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14257/jm_point.htm#CHDFGEGE) it seems that I need to create my own class which implements [ORADataFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/ORADataFactory.html) and works with my Oracle Object Type, which I've done, and use it when calling [createConsumer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14291/oracle/jms/AQjmsSession.html#createConsumer_javax_jms_Destination__java_lang_String__java_lang_Object__java_lang_String__boolean_), but I don't know how to get my ORADataFactory to be passed to createConsumer.

Do I have to create my own custom JMS Connector to get this working or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can solve it if you are using Spring: http://blog.javaforge.net/post/30858904340/oracle-advanced-queuing-spring-custom-types

In a "springless" environment just create your own message consumer like described in the article above.