# Reading OracleAQ message using Camel

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am trying to read from OracleAQ using camel. i followed the steps given in http://activemq.apache.org/jms-bridge-with-oracle-aq.html

I guess this would work if the messages are of type text.
In my case it's an object and I am getting a JMS-137 error.

I am unable to get around it using camel. 
any ideas/pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you put the same version of class which is transferred through the broker between the server and the client?

Comment: yes. my route is pretty simple.
<route>
     <from uri="oracleQueue:queue:db.ORACLE_QUEUE"/>
     <to uri="activemq:queue:JMS_QUEUE"/>
</route>
As you can see I am just trying to read out of the oracle aq and put it on a jms queue.

Comment: As Camel is using spring, you might (or might not) have success checking this SO thread out, it contains some pointers to blog posts dealing with Spring and Oracle AQ. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450925/spring-jms-and-oracle-aq

Comment: I'm note sure if this will suit you, but I just did a spike with [Scala + Akka + Camel](https://github.com/evbruno/akka-camel-oaq-example/) to deal with OAQ messages.